# Is any element in a group conjugate to its inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that every element $g\in G$ is conjugate to its inverse, or find a counterexample.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you prove it for a very simple group $G$?

Comment: Consider a group with $3$ elements

Comment: Or almost any abelian group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(123)$ and $(123)^{-1}=(132)$ are not conjugate in $A_3$.  We have $\sigma(123)\sigma^{-1}=(132)\implies \sigma=(23)$, which is not in $A_3$.

Or, very simply, as @RobertIsrael points out, most abelian groups provide a counterexample.

More generally, anything with nontrivial center, including $p$-groups ($p\gt2$), is likely to provide one.  For as soon as something in the center isn't its own inverse...

Answer (score 0):

Two elements $a$ and $b$ of a group $G$ are conjugates, if there exists an element $g$ in $G$ such that $gag^{−1} = b$ or equivalently $a= g^{-1}bg$.

This should help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a cyclic group.  Being Abelian, every element is conjugate only to itself.  But in a cyclic group of order greater than $2$, the generator is not an inverse of itself.